# Ruby Api How to change time format to (HH:mm) using Active:model:Serializer?

Tags: ruby, api, time-format

my db table column name is hora (translation:hour): type time. (Postgres).
Iḿ using Ruby 5.1 to develop my API i have installed gem active model serializer. my problem is that it shows me the field in this format: "hora":"2000-01-01T11:40:00Z", but i need only the hour with its minutes just like this: 11:40.
this is my actual output json
{"fecha":"2016-08-02","hora":"2000-01-01T11:40:00Z","importe":"86.0","medico":....}.

i need this:
{"fecha":"2016-08-02","hora":"11:40","importe":"86.0","medico":...}

```
my table
|hora                  |
|time withotu time zone|
| 09:30:00             |
| 11:40:00             |
| 10:10:00             |

mycontroller#show
 # GET /atencions/1
  def show
    render json: @atencion
  end


my model
class Atencion < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "atencion"
    belongs_to :medico
    belongs_to :paciente_planobrasocial
end

my model serializer
class AtencionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :medico
  belongs_to :paciente_planobrasocial
  attributes :fecha, :hora, :importe

end
```

is possible? how and where i can change the format of the time...
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, it works like this:

```
class AtencionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :medico
  belongs_to :paciente_planobrasocial
  attributes :fecha, :importe
  attribute :hora { object.hora.strftime "%H:%M" }
end
```

see https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md#overriding-attribute-methods